# Encryption/Signing SOAP with Different Certificates WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I'm currently working on what seems to be a fairly strange setup to communicate with another entity.  They require that I implement both the client an service sides of two SOAP endpoints (which is weird by itself in my opinion).  More to the point, they require the message to be both signed and encrypted (on top of normal TLS).

I'm not a huge cryptology expert, but from what I understand (and what the remote entity's technical staff tells me), I'm supposed to sign a message from my client to their service using my private key, and encrypt the message using their public key.  They do the opposite.  This make logical sense to me.

However, here's my issue: it doesn't seem like WCF easily supports this.  When I've implemented SOAP services before in Java using Spring, there was the concept of KeyManager and TrustManager.  In this way you could have the necessary crypto bits pulled from different stores.  In WCF, you can only specify one certificate per service/client.

I found this MSDN article with a possible solution:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729856(v=vs.110).aspx

However, it seems way too complex for what I imagine is a very common problem.

Before I go down implementing the above monster, I want to make sure I'm not missing something.  Maybe I'm missing a much simpler way?  Is what I'm trying to do really that unique?  Is WCF really this bad?  Is there a better third-party framework for .NET that better supports secure SOAP?

Thanks in advance.  I'm going crazy over here.